# How to make QString::fromLocal8Bit as default?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qstring

I'm using Qt 5.3.0. I need to add some Japanese characters into my code. I already add `BOM` but I still have to use `QString::fromLocal8Bit` to make characters to correctly be displayed.

For example:
I have a pushButton and I call `ui->pushButton->setText("浦");` then the button will have with weird marks instead of the character `浦`.

I have to use `ui->pushButton->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit("浦"));` to make it display right.

Is there a way to avoid the call of `fromLocal8Bit` by setting all creation of QString to pass the function fromLocal8Bit by default? without changing Qt source code.
Or any other good ideas?

Comment: I see no harm in using `QString::fromLocal8Bit`, maybe you could write a fast-user function as `QString MainWindow::str(QString s);` and use `setText(str("浦"));`

Comment: Have you tried `->setText( L"浦" );` ? The `L` prefix tells the compiler it's a UTF-16 string (that's a Windows thing, not Qt). So this avoids conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since qt5 you should be able to put japanese character as string literal into source code if the source files are saved in UTF-8 encoding. (I tried by copy/pasting the character, with qt5.3.1 and Mingw4.8.2 compiler, and I see the correct character in my button).
If you are loading the character from a file be sure to read it using a QTextStream with it's encoding set to "UTF-16" (if the file is encoded in UTF-16).